# How to force text from NumberPicker to stay on one line on small devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here's the following code :

```
@Composable
fun DurationPicker(
    label: String,
    onSelectTime: (FullHourWithSec) -> Unit,
    value: FullHourWithSec,
) {
    OutlinedBox(label = label) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            NumberPicker(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                label = { "%02d".format(it) },
                value = value.hours,
                onValueChange = {
                    onSelectTime(value.copy(hours = it))
                },
                dividersColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                range = 0..1000
            )
            Text(
                text = "h",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            )
            NumberPicker(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                label = { "%02d".format(it) },
                value = value.minutes,
                onValueChange = {
                    onSelectTime(value.copy(minutes = it))
                },
                dividersColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                range = 0..59
            )
            Text(
                text = "m",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            )
            NumberPicker(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                label = { "%02d".format(it) },
                value = value.seconds,
                onValueChange = {
                    onSelectTime(value.copy(seconds = it))
                },
                dividersColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                range = 0..59
            )
            Text(
                text = "s",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

On devices that have a small width such as Samsung Galaxy S20 (1440px), the picker display the number like this :

[image]

I want the 2 digits to stay on the same line like this :
[image]

I manage to make it works on the first one by removing padding from Texts but that's not a valid solution as it's good for devices with space to have some padding.

How can I adapt the padding from the Text to let enough space for the Number Picker Text to stay on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that works. Here's you go for those who are looking for the same thing.

```
@Composable
fun DurationPicker(
    label: String,
    onSelectTime: (FullHourWithSec) -> Unit,
    value: FullHourWithSec,
) {
    OutlinedBox(label = label) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                NumberPicker(
                    label = { "%02d".format(it) },
                    value = value.hours,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onSelectTime(value.copy(hours = it))
                    },
                    dividersColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                    range = 0..1000
                )
                Text(
                    text = "h",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                        .align(CenterVertically)
                )
            }

            Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                NumberPicker(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    label = { "%02d".format(it) },
                    value = value.minutes,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onSelectTime(value.copy(minutes = it))
                    },
                    dividersColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                    range = 0..59
                )
                Text(
                    text = "m",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                        .align(CenterVertically)
                )
            }

            Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                NumberPicker(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    label = { "%02d".format(it) },
                    value = value.seconds,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onSelectTime(value.copy(seconds = it))
                    },
                    dividersColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                    range = 0..59
                )
                Text(
                    text = "s",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 8.dp)
                        .align(CenterVertically)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is to consider that the NumberPicker and the Text of each unit should occupy 1/3 of the screen. Then, I just center the unit Text vertically